# MERN CRUD Can't edit the input fields when try to edit a user

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

Im trying to make my project with MERN and I'm doing the CRUD of a user, but when I get to the part of updating the user, I use the value with the mongoDB data, to be already filled when the admin get's in the page.

But when I try to edit it, I can't even type or delete inside the field...

This is my code on React with the fetch to get the information from the backend:

```
const EditUtilizador = () => {
  const { userId } = useParams();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState([]);
  const nav = useNavigate();
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = (data) => putUser(data);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`/userdb/users/${userId}`, {
      headers: { Accept: "application/json" },
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => {
        setLoading(false);
        setUserInfo(response);
      });
    return () => setUserInfo([]);
  }, []);

  const putUser = (data) => {
    fetch(`/userdb/users/${userId}`, {
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      method: "PUT",
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          alert("Utilizador atualizado com sucesso");
          nav("/admin/utilizadores");
        } else {
          alert("Algo de errado não esta certo");
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error:", error);
      });
  };

  if (loading) {
    return (
      <>
        <HeaderAdmin />
        <h1>A carregar</h1>
      </>
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
      <HeaderAdmin />
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="name"
          value={`${userInfo.name}`}
          {...register("name")}
        />
        <br />
        <input
          type="text"
          name="email"
          value={`${userInfo.email}`}
          {...register("email")}
        />
        <br />
        <input
          type="password"
          name="password"
          placeholder="Nova Password"
          {...register("password")}
        />
        <br />
        <br />
        <button type="submit">Atualizar Conta</button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
};
```

As you can see in the return, inside the input I get the value already the value that is in the database, but for some reason I don't know, I'm not able to edit it...
It looks like this in the page:
[image: Website]
I try to type inside the field and I can't change what's in it?
What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

```
const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState([]);
```

Since userInfo is array and you are storing value in input as userInfo.name which is basically method to get key value in object so make it object add key value as default

```
const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState({
    name:"",
    email:""
});
```

and to change input use onChange method on input

i.e

```
<input
type="text"
name="name"
value={`${userInfo.name}`}    
onChange={((e)=>{
     setUserInfo(pre=>{
pre.name=e.target.value;
})
})}
 />
```

this change will you to edit and update as well and pass the update date in put api

Comment: I've done everything you did, but when I go and even try to type, it crashes and my page becomes white... there is something wrong... do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: Can u ssend the console error?